# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::$comment

Tags: laravel

I have a small project in which there should be a comment for each post. I tried to do this using the following code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Repository\ICommentRepository;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write Your Code..
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'body'=>'required',
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $this->comment->createComment($data);
        return back();
    }
}
```

With the following error
‍‍`Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\CommentController::$comment`

After a bit of searching, I realized my mistake and corrected it as follows

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(IAdminRepository $comment){
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }
    /**
    * Write Your Code..
    *
    * @return string
    **/
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $request->validate([
            'body'=>'required',
        ]);
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $this->comment->createPost($input);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Then I got the same error as before and it showed me the same code while I was changing the contents of the code

[image]

I tried to clear the cache with `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan optimize` but nothing changed.
pleas help me

Comment: Where did you define the property itself? `$this->comment` assigns a value to it, but it does not define the property. Also, just as a notice: check the naming of your variables - why does `$comment` contain an instance of `IAdminRepository`?

Comment: I wrote this with the Repository design pattern and defined the comment in the construct above

Comment: can you show your IAdminrepository class?

Comment: @EmekaOkafor why is the content of that class relevant to resolve the given error message?

Comment: @Nico Haase Am surprised at your question, if you do have an answer please give, this is not facebook or social media, this is for programmers to help one another.

Comment: Yeah, then feel free to provide help. Why is the content of that class relevant for the given problem?

Comment: @samira if changing the code itself does not change the code shown in the error message, are you sure that you are editing the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

here is what she need

```
private $comment; 

public function __construct(IAdminRepository $comment){
    $this->comment = $comment;
}
if this is not working then you have something wrong in you IAdminRepository class
```

Comment: I want the store function to be done with repository. Is it possible?

Comment: Please share more details, such that others can learn from your answer. What did you change, and why?

Comment: i just make relation and then store comments with post id to the related post

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it. How does this resolve the error message from the original code?

Comment: ok above first post.php is post controller and the other one is comment model. i have made relation between them and then in store function public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $request->validate([
            'body'=>'required',
        ]);
 $post = Post::find($request->get('post_id'));
        $post->comments()->save($comment);
        return back();
    }

Comment: @NicoHaase check now

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Even when I completely change the contents of CommentController.php, the same previous code is displayed in the error, even when I clear the cache.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/samirapadidar2000/articleweb1.git  i push gitlab

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{

    private $comment;

    public function __construct(IAdminRepository $comment){
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }
    /**
    * Write Your Code..
    *
    * @return string
    **/
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $request->validate([
            'body'=>'required',
        ]);
        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
        $this->comment->createPost($input);
        return back();
    }
}
```

you did not define the $comment variable and you are trying to assign value to it.

Comment: I did this, but it still gives the previous error

Comment: then can you show the content of that class IAdminRepository?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variable comment before the line for the constructor.
i.e

```
private $comment; //this line is important and it was missing in your code

public function __construct(IAdminRepository $comment){
    $this->comment = $comment;
}
```